# Wrong date value inserted into database

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc, oracle11gr2

The database is Oracle 11g2 Express with the default schema hr.

Code of the class model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HR.EMPLOYEES")
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private Date hireDate; // java.util.Date
    private String job_id;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="EMPLOYEES_SEQ", sequenceName="EMPLOYEES_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="EMPLOYEES_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Formula(value="FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @Column(name="HIRE_DATE")
    public Date getHireDate() {
        return hireDate;
    }
    public void setHireDate(Date hireDate) {
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
    }
    @Column(name="JOB_ID")
    public String getJob_id() {
        return job_id;
    }
    public void setJob_id(String job_id) {
        this.job_id = job_id;
    }

}
```

Implementation of the class model :

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public UserDAOImpl() {

    }

    public UserDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<User> list() {        
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> listUser = (List<User>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(User.class)
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
        return listUser;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User get(int id) {

        String hql = "from User where id=" + id;
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> listUser = (List<User>) query.list();

        if (listUser != null && !listUser.isEmpty()) {
            return listUser.get(0);
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(int id) {
        User userToDelete = new User();
        userToDelete.setId(id);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(userToDelete);
    }

}
```

The JSP page :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>${titre}</title>
<style type="text/css">
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>${titre}</h1>
        <table>
            <form:form action="save" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
            <form:hidden path="id"/>
            <tr>
                <td>Firstname:</td>
                <td><form:input path="firstname"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lastname:</td>
                <td><form:input path="lastname"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hiredate:</td>
                <td><form:input path="hireDate"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Job_id:</td>
                <td><form:input path="job_id"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save">
                </td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/' />"><input type="button" value="Annuler" /></a></td>
            </tr>        
            </form:form>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When clicking the submit button in the JSP page then data are inserted into table. But the date column is changed from 18/08/16 to 08/06/17 ! So what is wrong ?

Comment: I'm going to bet you've got different timezones in your system.

Comment: Where you convert the string to a date?

Comment: Note: don't represent "local dates" using `Date`: a `Date` is an instant in time, a number of milliseconds since `1970-1-1 00:00:00 UTC`; a local date is just `YYYY-mm-dd`. For example: if a child born at midnight in 18th August in London, its date of birth is YYYY/08/18; but a child born at exactly the same instant in NYC has date of birth YYYY/08/17. You can't represent "dates" by instants.

Comment: So with which java datatype is the best to represent local date ?

Comment: @pheromix [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Comment: it causes `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 78670611`

Comment: What do your dates mean? 18/08/16, is that 18 August 2016? And that was changed to 08 June 2017? I don't understand what this may possibly have to do with different time zones. If that is a typo and in fact the difference is "the next day", please edit your post to correct it.

Comment: 18/08/16 is 18 August 2016 , and it changed to 08 June 2017 after submitting the form. It does not rely on timezone cause the years are very different : one year difference ! It is not me who changed the date , it is not typo , and it is not matter of next day !

Answer (score 0):

Date is always a hard to use when going through HTML forms to a database.
In JDBC, you should use the java.util.Date object as much as possible and checking that the locale on the Database is the same as the one on your server (transaltion from String to Date and vice-versa) and that the configured timezone is also the same.

I don't think using LocalDate will help you regarding database recording as I'm not sure weither the database driver (or the database fromework - as you use JPA you should use Hibernate or something like this) will support it.

Sometimes, using string to represent a birthdate is simplier ...

Moreover, in your code, you don't show us where you convert your string from the input form to a date, maybe the issue lies here ...

Regards,

Loïc

Answer (score 0):

Try to set @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy") for you Date variable in your @Entity class (with pattern that is suitable for you).

Ex.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy")
@Column(name = "auctionDate")
private LocalDate auctionDate;
```